# postgresql, jsonb field, array append via jsonb_set and jsonb_array_length

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have postgresql with jsonb field that always contains array. 
I need to append new values to that array or update already existing values by index.

Looks like `jsonb_set` function meet my requirements. And for append new element i just need to max array index and update element with it.
But i have a trouble doing this. Lets make it step by step.
We have table campaigns with jsonb field team_members.

```
 select id, jsonb_set(team_members, '{0}', '{"name" : "123"}') from campaigns;
 id  |     jsonb_set     
 -----+-------------------
 102 | [{"name": "123"}]
```

Okay great, if set path '{0}' statically everything works.
Lets do that dynamically

SQL for getting array length (it is our index for append)

```
  select  '{' || jsonb_array_length(team_members) || '}'::text from campaigns;
  ?column? 
  ----------
  {0}
```

Getting all together

```
   select jsonb_set(team_members, '{' || jsonb_array_length(team_members) || '}', '{"name" : "123"}') from campaigns;
```

> **ERROR**:  function jsonb_set(jsonb, text, unknown) does not exist
>   LINE 1: select jsonb_set(team_members, '{' ||
>   jsonb_array_length(tea...
>              ^    HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might

need to add explicit type casts.

My question is - how can i get rid of this error ? What i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to append, `||` is better candidate for you

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure i followed you, can you show me example please ?

Comment: At first I did not understand you part with index. Now I think I get it. and suggested example in answer

Comment: `select '[]'::jsonb || '{"name": "123"}'::jsonb || '{"name": "456"}'::jsonb;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?..

```
t=# with jpath as (select concat('{',0,'}')::text[] path) select jsonb_set('[]'::jsonb,path,'{"name": "123"}'::jsonb) from jpath;
     jsonb_set
-------------------
 [{"name": "123"}]
(1 row)
```

In your case should be like:

```
select 
  jsonb_set(
    team_members
  , concat('{',jsonb_array_length(team_members),'}')::text[]
  , '{"name" : "123"}'
  ) 
from campaigns;
```

Comment: Great ! I don't know about concat. 

Only one moment: concat('{',jsonb_array_length(team_members),'}')::text[]

you forgot about colon after )

thank you